# ngx-translate's getTranslation function doesn't listen to Observable changes

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I am creating a custom Angular ngx-translate Loader which tries to get translations from local storage, before making an API call and updating the local storage with the new translations.

Here's my `getTranslation` function:

```js
    getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        // get translations from local storage
        const translations = new BehaviorSubject(
            JSON.parse(this.localStorageService.getItem('translations'))
        );

        // get translations from API
        this.myApiService.get('/translations/' + lang).subscribe(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                // update local Storage with new translations
                this.localStorageService.setItem('translations', JSON.stringify(response.data));
                translations.next(response.data);
            }
        });

        return translations;
    }
```

The problem is, that `getTranslation` doesn't seem to update the Observable on `translations.next()` and continues using the translations that were initially set with

```js
const translations = new BehaviorSubject(
     JSON.parse(this.localStorageService.getItem('translations'))
);
```

until I reload my app.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just put `const translations = new BehaviorSubject(...)` as a public variable and subscribe to it in the component needed. Your code is not working because `translations`'s scope in inside the function. Also, you're returning `translations` before the subscribtion has finished its job. It also wont work because you're returning the value and not the reference of that variable.

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi: I never call the `getTranslation` function manually - ngx-translate does it all automatically. It even uses the value I iniatially pass into the Observable and just ignores when I update it. My variable shouldn't be the problem per se but how ngx-translate handles the Observable. `translations` is an Observable so and I can pass the subscription return value into it with `.next`. That's the whole point behind using a BehaviourSubeject.

Comment: Perhaps I am just very bad at describing my problem. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558004/update-translations-in-loader-of-ngx-translate) right here, which is exactly my problem but perhaps explained in a better way. Since it doesn't have any replies though, it sadly didn't help me.

Comment: I just don't understand why you put the BS inside the function, that's all! If you need to update something when `getTranslation` gets called via this BS just put it in the service, do the `.next` inside the `getTranslation` and subscribe to it in the components needed.

Comment: Ah, my apologies if I've come off a bit rude. This has been haunting me for the last 2 days now.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi The problem is that even if I subscribe in the component where I need the translations, ngx-translate doesn't update and keeps using the translations I initially pushed into the subject whenever I use the `| translate` pipe. I can subscribe to the event and call every ngx-translate refresh function known to human kind but it just won't use the new translations.

Comment: My guess is, that ngx-translate calls `getTranslation` and uses the first value in the Observable to pass the strings to some other component that handles the pipes and other ngx-translate function calls. After that it just ignores any following updates to the observable. All I gotta figure out is how to get ngx-translate to refresh the values it uses to parse the keys to translated strings.

Comment: Holy guacamole. I think you helped me figure it out. I will have to test my solution a bit but if it works, I'll post it as answer. Thanks for being so patient! @JacopoSciampi

Comment: No problem at all, I guess everyone become "salty" after some hours trying literally everything having as the only result a big "Owh, it's working still". I'll wait your asnwer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like pushing two different values into the observable in the `getTranslation` function messes with ngx-translate - I found a work around though.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works and solves my problem, so I'm just gonna go ahead and use it.

CustomTranslateLoader:

```js
getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const translations = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);          
    translations.next(JSON.parse(this.localStorageService.getItem('translations')));
    return translations;
}

loadTranslation(lang) {
    return this.blockpitApiService.get('/translations/' + lang);
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
    constructor(
        private translate: TranslateService,
        private translateService: CustomTranslateLoader,
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) {

        language = translate.getBrowserLang();
        translate.setDefaultLang(language);

        // load translations from server and update translations
        this.translateService.loadTranslation(language).subscribe(response => {
            this.localStorageService.setItem('translations', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            translate.setTranslation(language, response.data);
            translate.use(language);
        });
     }
```

Since ngx-translate simply ignores when we push new translations into the observable, we can simply call `translate.setTranslation(language, response.data)` and `translate.use(language)`, to update the values used when translating.
By calling this as soon as our api call is finished, we initially see the translation that are first set in `getTranslation` which ngx-translation calls automatically and the api translations as soon as they are available when we `.subscribe` to the function in our `app.component.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, I understand exactly you, but I think when you call the `getTranslation()` it reads the json from localStorage saving to `translation` constans... and after you calling the api but you are not update the `translation` variable just saving to localstorage.. then you are returning. So when you reload the page ofc it reads from the localstorage again BUT this time there is that translations what you get from the API on the first time.

Comment: I am working with an Observable here and passing the new translations into the Observable with `translations.next(response.data)`. This should usually be enough to update the translations, but apparently it's not in this case.